# ref.current.setAttribute is not a function

Tags: reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-16-2fss1

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Autosuggest from "react-autosuggest";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

const Wrapper = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof inputRef.current !== "undefined") {
      inputRef.current.setAttribute("de-di-var", "");
    }
  }, []);

  return <App ref={inputRef} />;
};
const inputProps = {
  placeholder: "",
  value: "",
  onChange: (event, { newValue }) => {
    console.log("change");
  },
  label: "",
  feedback: null,
  error: null
};
const App = React.forwardRef(
  ({ error }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <h4>Reference</h4>
        <Autosuggest
          inputProps={inputProps}
          ref={ref}
          suggestions=""
          undefined={false}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);

render(<Wrapper />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Ok, so I am trying to use a ref in my wrapper component and then use the function setAttribute to add an attribute to the input field inside the component Autocomplete, but it won't let me. Is there any reason for this, because I am struggling to figure out why ref.current may be undefined, because that's what I am assuming I get the message error.

Comment: Why do you assume that there is such function `setAttribute` within its reference? Where did you read it?

Comment: In my previous question, an user proposed to me that i should use ref.current.setAttribute(), but it seems that he removed his answer.

Comment: Well, there is no such function so it won't work.

Comment: He edited his answer out. I hate when users do this. Isn't there a way to use setAttribute on a ref?

Comment: Its a library, not every reference is the same, you should refer to the libraries docs.

Comment: Is there a way to add an attribute without value to the input field in Autosuggest? I can't seem to find any way to do this without putting it in the input field myself, which is not a viable solution since it's a library and I shouldn't modify it.

Comment: Its entirely another question, you should ask another specific question about the `AutoSuggest` use case. I suggest asking in their Github too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function within `AutoSuggest` reference.

You can check it by logging the reference:

```
const Wrapper = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inputRef.current);
    console.log(inputRef.current.setAttribute);
    // inputRef.current.setAttribute('de-di-var', '');
  }, []);

  return <App ref={inputRef} />;
};
```

[image: Edit React 16]

Comment: Is there a way to add an attribute without value to the input field in Autosuggest? I can't seem to find any way to do this without putting it in the input field myself, which is not a viable solution since it's a library and I shouldn't modify it.